# LINQ Group by and return all columns in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Datatable

```
     ID       RS
    1484    1751
    1668    15277
    1677    3925


    1484    1214
    1668    7940
    1677    696


    1484    1849
    1668    7781
    1677    484


    1484    1395
    1668    5715
    1677    416
```

& I want following results after applying Linq Group by and Binding 2 dimensional array

```
 var a = new string[][] { 
                new[] { "1484   ","[1751, 1214, 1849, 1395]" }, 
                new[] { "1668" ,"[15277, 7940, 7781, 5715"} ,
                new[] { "1677","[3925,696, 484, 416} 
                       };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a =
    items
        .ToLookup(x => x.ID, x => x.RS)
        .Select(x => new []
        {
            x.Key.ToString(), 
            String.Format("[{0}]", String.Join(", ", x))
        })
        .ToArray();
```

That gives me:

[image: a]

Answer (score 0):

You need to Group on the basisi of field `ID`

```
        var result = (from d in data
                                     group d by d.ID into gr
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         ID = gr.Key,
                                         DataList = gr.ToList()
                                     }).ToList();
```

Here you can get the List of Grouped values.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
Datacontexts db=new Datacontext();
    var query=from i in db.table group by ID select new{i.Id,i.Rs};
```

Comment: @Sajidlodi - you need to delete your comment. Stack Overflow devolve in this way.